# Could a 4 pole 3.5mm jack be used to power a RGB LED?

Tags: led, connector

I'm hoping to make my LED pluggable into a jack of some kind. Could a 4 pole 3.5mm jack be used? Could each pole carry 3v-5v?

Here's the LED: http://www.tandyonline.co.uk/5mm-full-colour-rgb-led-common-cathode.html

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I would really suggest you elaborate on your question, if you want a usable answer. What kind of power would this LED be, why 4 pole, what else is sharing the jack?

AFAIK, those phono jacks aren't very applicable for power applications as they typically short-circuit the poles during mating and unmating

Comment: Sorry. The LED needs a minimum operating voltage of 3V and my device is powered by 2x AAs. I'm hoping to have a easy way to plug and unplug the LED. I thought 4 pole might be good since the LED has 4 pins. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: What is this "4-pin LED"? Do you have a part number or any identifying information? Even a photo would be helpful.

Comment: @rdtsc I've added a photo now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically, yes, it would work.  But it's probably not a good idea.  Here's how this family of connectors tends to perform, including TRRS, TRS, and TS of any size:

1. They're typically used with analog line-level signals that can reach up to +-15V in some cases, so voltage is not a problem for you.
2. They're not suitable for high currents because of the small contact area.  If you're running 1A or less in total, it's probably okay, but I'd want to verify specs if my estimate got above 100mA.  I say "in total" because the common return has the same rating as any other contact.
3. They're not suitable for hot plugging or unplugging without careful analysis because they rake the contacts across each other.  If you imagine a plug or unplug event in slow motion, think about the different circuits that are made each time a jack's contact crosses a boundary between the plug's contacts.

Comment: Very interesting. If not 4 pole 3.5mm jack, what connector would you rather recommend?

Comment: Try XLR connectors. They come in various numbers of poles, I think I've seen some with 6+, but 3 poles followed by 5 poles are the most common. But there are probably 10's if not 100's of other types of connectors that might be suitable. Tradeoffs include price, size, ruggedness, locking mechanisms, expected life time in plugging/unplugging cycles hotplugging advantages, etc etc

Comment: Yep, that should work.  Whatever connector you choose, try to wire it similarly to other standards that already use that connector.  For example, DMX-512 uses 5-pin XLR with pin 1 as ground, pins 2/3 as data1 +/-, and pins 4/5 as optional data2 +/-.  For another example, professional microphones use 3-pin XLR with pin 1 as ground and pins 2/3 as signal +/- with optional phantom power as +48V via 6.8k resistors on both signal pins.  Other connectors have their own pre-existing standards.  Try to cause minimal damage if one of your plugs ends up in someone else's jack or vice-versa.

Comment: In that case, how about PS/2 connectors? They should preclude the raking problem and should be able to carry that needed amount of voltage and current, right?

Comment: Do you know the standard pinout?  It should be easy to look up.  Just make sure that your LED driver won't blow up a mouse or keyboard and that your LED's will tolerate a PC motherboard.  Or, a common trick is to reverse the gender so that it's impossible to plug them together that way, but it doesn't completely solve the problem because now your LED driver can plug into a PC.  If that's okay, then you're fine.  Also look up the specs of that connector.  It'll probably handle the required current, but the pins are a bit smaller than most connectors so you'll want to make sure.

Comment: At this point, it doesn't really save time to ask here because it's a googling problem either way, and you know your needs better than we do.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the jack would be able to handle it. Small jacks I've used before had a rating of 1 amp per contact and 30 volts between them. Some are capable of far greater current, IIRC around 10 amps, and 60 volts, as the large quarter inch jacks were often used for loudspeaker connections.

But to be sure, you need to get the datasheet for the parts in question. If they aren't available, ask your supplier what the maximum voltage/current ratings for it are.

Edit: AaronD +1 for mentioning hot plugging/unplugging

You can probably get away with the hotplugging issue, since it would be a relatively short time that the short circuit would exist, and while it would not be advisable for professional applications, the internal resistance of the AA batteries would make it vaguely safe. But one solution which could get complicated, is sockets often have a way of detecting when the plug is fully inserted - you could use some circuitry that prevents anything but ground being applied to the socket's contacts until the plug is fully inserted.

Comment: As an audio guy myself, I'm a little concerned to see 1/4" TS plugs used for speakers.  They were popular when amplifiers were less powerful and speakers had higher impedance, both of which serve to reduce current.  The flat spring on a round plug doesn't leave a lot of area for current to flow, not to mention the safety hazard of having a modern, high-powered amp behind a bare 1/4" plug.  You might as well plug the amp's end of that wire into a wall socket.

Comment: Lol! I must try that some time

Comment: 120Vrms (U.S. outlets) across an 8ohm speaker = 1800watts.  Entirely reasonable for a smallish modern PA system.

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you meant plug the amp output into a mains wall socket!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jack connector, but "pigtail" connectors are far more convenient for power delivery (you cannot short the poles with other items).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_connector#Cylindrical_connectors

Answer (score 0):

You can use it.

If you have the plug connected to the LED only, and your three resistors (you will need three resistors or an equivalent circuit) on the jack side then any momentary shorting is of no consequence.

The maximum current will be thorough the common lead it and it won't be more than high tens of mA or the LED will be short-lived. Easily within the capabilities of such a plug/jack system.

For example, [this](https://tensility.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/product_doc/document/4375/54-00179.pdf) inexpensive SMT Tensility jack is rated at 0.5A.

[image]

Do **not** connect more than one wire from the battery directly to the jack (without resistors), as the short-circuit current from a fresh alkaline AA cell can easily exceed the maximum current of the jack so the momentary shorting could damage the jack (or plug, but that's less likely).